# HTML Marquee stop

Tags: html, css, marquee

```
<h2><marquee behavior="slide" scrollamount="20">HTML PROJECT</marquee></h2>
```

I want the HTML PROJECT headline coming from right to left to stop in the middle. I can't use any js code so i need to do this using only CSS. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: use css3 animation concept

Comment: Don't use `marquee` tag, it's deprecated. Look for some css3 solutions instead since you can't use js. Just google for "css3 marquee"

Take a look a this link for example

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-animation-advanced-marquee/

Comment: Why you should avoid using marquee [Check Here](http://caniuse.com/#search=marquee)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you need to  following code `width="50%" style="float:right"`

```html
<h2><marquee behavior="slide" width="50%" style="float:right" scrollamount="20">HTML PROJECT</marquee></h2>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<h2 style="text-align:right"><marquee behavior="slide" scrollamount="20" width="50%">HTML PROJECT</marquee></h2>
```

Actually i found it. All i had to do was place the text to begin from the right side. Thanks anyway!